# How do you investigate a system crash when there are no records/logs?

Tags: server, crash, log

### **TL;DR**

1. How does one actually investigates a system crash when the logs don't show anything?
2. Secondly, how do I prepare for future crashes? Is it possible to have more aggressive/accurate logging? In case the system panics or freezes in a way that it didn't even had time to log.

   ---

Few weeks ago I got 3 VPS machines (KVM) from a provider, and 2 of them crashed after a week ( at random/different times ). They all had 512MB ram ( with 512mb swap space ).

One one of them actually was shutdown and had a "offline" label in the provider's admin panel, and the other was kinda frozen, the panel showed "Online" but I couldn't ssh or access to it though web console.

None of them were running anything cpu/memory intensive tasks. One was just a openvpn server (with 2-3users) and the other just nginx+php serving a static site. Both of them had like 200-300 available memory at all times and the cpu was below 10% usage.

I had Netdata monitoring installed. So I had a history of almost everything. I looked up every single chart and graph right before the crashes. There was no spike or sudden increase in CPU/Memory/Disk/Network/Process/Firewall usage.

I looked up every single log file under `/var/logs/`. I read them line by line (before crash happened). I also used `journalctl`. There was no error, no warnings, no out of memory, no process killing, just normal events.

Both the servers that crashed had a `syslog` that looked like this:

[image]
As you can see the ufw is just blocking random spammers right before the crash and then there is no log. Also the boot you see at `20:41:02` is the hard/forced reboot we did after the crash happened, just to get the system back online.

When I asked the provide they said everything looks ok on their side and the reason my servers crashed was because 512MB RAM was too low and I had to upgrade.

Also, there are 2 things that I randomly read on the internet that I thought I ask here if they're an actual thing.

- "Micro RAM spikes, for example rotating ram tables to disk, etc"
- a parameter called `journal_data_writeback` that if it's enabled, the system might miss writing logs to the disk during a crash.

Comment: Pictures of text are hard to read, but I didn't see mention of you looking in /var/crash/ for application crash details. It's the first place I'd look; but are you talking system crash? program crash? as 'crash' is unspecific and the type of 'crash' does control where you look.

Comment: @guiverc I editted the question's title. I was referring to a system crash. Also, there was no `/var/crash` when I tried to find it. That's why I didn't mention it

Comment: What are you running?   Ubuntu is setup to write kernel crashes to /var/crash/ (a directory) so are you even running Ubuntu?  or have you modified your `kdump_config` to point it elsewhere? in which case this is useful information that should be provided (including your release of Ubuntu; or in your case what you're using since it's likely not Ubuntu)

Comment: @guiverc I'm running `Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-62-generic x86_64)` on all systems. Um.. I never heard of `kdump`. I just copied what you wrote and tried to run `kdump-config` command and it says `command not found, did you mean: command 'kdump-config' from deb kdump-tools`. Is this supposed to be included in all Ubuntu releases by default?

Comment: Not exactly; I was thinking of the `linux-crashdump` package and a modified kdump-config param  (though related to `kdump-tools`).  Your setup has dumps disabled and reduced logging which is possibly why you can't find it.  Sorry I can't help.

Comment: @guiverc You know you're actually helping me a ton right? You just told me about a mechanism I should have had in the first place and I didn't because I didn't even know it existed. This is the whole point of this question. I wanted to know how to prepare for the future so next time I get a system crash I can have something to look at. Anyway the `linux-crashdump` package also seems to be missing. I assume this was the provider's decision to exclude these packages from the Ubuntu ISO. Can you tell me which one do I have to install? do I install the `linux-crashdump` or `kdump-tools` or both?

Comment: Nevermind. I found out installing `linux-crashdump` first will also include `kdump-tools`. @guiverc if you post the information you provided me in the form of an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After talking to [guiverc](https://askubuntu.com/users/469152/guiverc) in the comments, I realized that I actually had to have a package called `linux-crashdump`. But because the server was installed using a minimal Ubuntu template, It did not come with this package preinstalled so when the crash happened nothing was logged. That's why I couldn't find anything.

For anyone who's investigating their crash reason and wonder why there are no log files in `/var/crash`, make sure you install `linux-crashdump` so hopefully next time you can have something to look at ;)